# best way to handle add with firestore offline

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I create a code that add in firestore and it's work as expected when app online but when I turned internet off the `await` function hanging but the data updated in cash but the widget dosen't update until future function response how can Do it ?

```
Firestore.instance.settings(
  persistenceEnabled: true,
);
firestore = Firestore.instance;

Future<void> update(String itemId, Map<String,dynamic> data) async {
  return await shoppingItemsRef.document(itemId).updateData(data);
}
```

how can if user in offline mode throw this future function return response or by any way .

Answer (score 0):

With Firestore SDKs, write operations do not fully complete until the write is committed on the server.  I expect that the Future will not resolve until the call to `updateData` has fully completed.  This means that `await` will be "stuck" until the app comes online again.

However, after the call to `updateData`, you should still see changes immediately for subsequent queries and listeners, before the write fully completes on the server.

Comment: yes that's exactly what code behavior doing , but I want to know how can avoid this ! by don't wait update !

Comment: Don't call await if you don't want that codepath to be stuck while offline.